Flutter Firebase Background Notification Sound Won't Stop When App is Inactive
I am working on a Flutter app for a cloud kitchen food ordering business. The app uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send notifications when a new order arrives. A sound is played whenever a notification is received, whether the app is active, in the background, or completely inactive.
The expected behavior:

The sound should stop when the user clicks on the notification, regardless of whether the app is in the foreground, background, or inactive.

The problem:

If the app is active or in the background, the sound stops correctly when the notification is clicked.
However, if the app is inactive (not on screen or killed), the sound continues to play indefinitely because the audio player fails to stop.

It seems like the app cannot access the audio player when it is inactive, and I am struggling to implement a solution that handles this scenario properly.
Here is the code I have used to implement FCM notifications and handle the audio player:
main.dart
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:maalik/app.dart';
import 'package:maalik/services/firebase_api.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

String? fcmToken;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

  await NotificationServices.initLocalNotification();

  final notificationServices = NotificationServices();
  fcmToken = await notificationServices.initFcmNotification();

  FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
  };
  PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
    return true;
  };
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.app.setAutomaticDataCollectionEnabled(false);
  await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  });
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  NotificationServices().listenNotification();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    log('Notification clicked: ${message.notification}');
    _stopAudio(); // Stop the audio when notification is tapped
  });
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _stopAudio() async {
  try {
    if (player != null) {
      await player!.stop();
      await player!.release();
      player = null;
      log("Audio stopped from background notification");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    log("Error stopping audio: $e");
  }
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  log('Raw Message Data: ${message.data}');
  log('Message Origin: ${message.senderId}');
  log("Handling background message: ${message.notification}");
  if (message.data['channelId'] == 'order_received') {
    audioPlayerStart();
  }
}

firebase_api.dart
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:maalik/main.dart';
import 'package:sound_mode/sound_mode.dart';
import 'package:volume_controller/volume_controller.dart';

AudioPlayer? player;

class NotificationServices {
  final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static Future initLocalNotification({bool isScheduled = false}) async {
    final androidInit = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/launcher_icon');
    final iosInit = DarwinInitializationSettings();
    final initSetting = InitializationSettings(android: androidInit, iOS: iosInit);

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initSetting,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse response) async {
        log("Notification clicked: ${response.payload}");
        if (player != null) {
          await player!.stop();
          await player!.release();
          player = null;
          log("Audio stopped");
        }
      },
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: _backgroundNotificationHandler,
    );

    log("inside initlocalNotification");
    AndroidNotificationChannel orderReceiveChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'order_received',
      'Order Notification Channel',
      description: 'Order Notification Channel',
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      playSound: false,
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'),
    );

    const AndroidNotificationChannel otherNotificationChannel =
        AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'other_notification',
      'Other Notification Channel',
      description: 'Other Notification Channel',
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      playSound: true,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(orderReceiveChannel);
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(otherNotificationChannel);
  }

  Future<String?> initFcmNotification() async {
    validateSoundFile();
    try {
      await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        announcement: false,
        badge: true,
        carPlay: false,
        criticalAlert: false,
        provisional: false,
        sound: true,
      );
      log("inside request permission");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    try {
      final fcmToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      log('fcmToken: $fcmToken');
      return fcmToken;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return '';
  }

  listenNotification() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      log("inside listenNotification");
      if (message.data['channelId'] == 'order_received') {
        audioPlayerStart();
      }
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
          message.data['channelId'] ?? 'other_notification',
          'Order Notification Channel',
          playSound: false,
          sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'),
          priority: Priority.max,
        );

        DarwinNotificationDetails iosDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(
          sound: 'notification.wav',
        );

        NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
          android: androidDetails,
          iOS: iosDetails,
        );

        _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          notificationDetails,
        );
      }
    });
  }
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void audioPlayerStart() async {
  try {
    var ringer_mode = await SoundMode.ringerModeStatus;

    if (ringer_mode.name == 'normal') {
      VolumeController volumeController = VolumeController();
      volumeController.maxVolume(showSystemUI: false);

      if (player == null) {
        player = AudioPlayer(playerId: "customNotificationPlayer");
        await player?.setVolume(1.0);
      }

      if (player != null) {
        await player!.play(AssetSource('notification.mp3'));

        await Future.delayed(Duration(minutes: 2));

        await player!.stop();
        await player!.release();
        await player!.dispose();

        player = null;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error playing sound: $e");
  }
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void _backgroundNotificationHandler(NotificationResponse response) {
  log("Background notification clicked");
  _stopAudio();
}

